# Paperclip. How not to save empty file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want user to be able to save up to 5 files (anything less than that is fine), so here's my new action (place_photos are Paperclip attachments, Place :has_many PlacePhoto):

```
def new
  @place = Place.new
  5.times { @place.place_photos.build }
  ...
end
```

My form looks as follows (a little bit simplified):

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :place_photos do |photo| %>
  <%= photo.input :photo %>
  <%= photo.input :description %>
<% end %>
```

As a result 5 file fields are generated. After the form is submitted, empty PlacePhoto records are created if files are not provided. How to prevent from saving empty records and not to get an error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `place` model, you can validate `place_photos` as below:

```
Class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :place_photos , :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['photo'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I just changed it a little bit:   accepts_nested_attributes_for :place_photos , :reject_if => proc { |attributes| !attributes['photo'].present? }, :allow_destroy => true

Comment: :) yes! you need to make it photo rather than data.